# Extending bottom border in UL when using styled bullet

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a UL with some items. I used a CSS circle trick to change the bullet into a circle. However, I want a border to appear underneath each item to provide a separation bewtween the items.

Since I styled the bullets and used list-style: none, the "bullet" is placed -1em, which means the border doesn't extend under the bullet.

```
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li class="selected">Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>



ul {
    margin: 0.75em 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
li:before {
    content:"";
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    left: -1em;
    top: 0.9em;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
selected:before {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Here's the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jKZ4k1i5V8LTj4AcoUyA?p=preview)

Any suggestions on how I make the bottom border extend underneath the entire list item, including the bullet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forcing the bullet and the text on different lines by making the bullet display as a block element and then trying to rectify this using `top` and `left` properties.

Display your bullet inline and give it a margin on the right:

```
li:before {
    content:"";
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right:0.3em;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Should you need the space within your list items, pad them out some:

```
li {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    padding:3px 4px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/e4ht6c5y/1/)

Comment: Thank! I love the this approach a lot more since it avoids using negatives.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

On Your li style, you can add:

```
padding-left:1em;
margin-left:-1em;
```

The padding will offset all the contents inside to the right, so they are in line with the border.  The margin will then set the li itself back to the left to keep it in it's original position.

plunker fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/zhir039xFgkF0mjKLJyq?p=preview

Comment: I like this answer a lot too

Comment: If you don't want to allow the text to wrap under the bullet, this answer or Edmund Reed's answer can work for you.  That's just a matter of preference or context though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plunker with the correct code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ocbEEs6wylufmcPL88vh?p=preview

Basically you need to do the following:

- remove all padding from the ul
- add left padding of 1em to the li

  ```
  ul {
      margin: 0.75em 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
  }

  li {
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      border-bottom-color: red;
      padding-left: 1em;
  }
  ```

and boom, there you have it.